# How do you define your environment such as to use [...] for some parameter(s)?

Tags: environments, optional-arguments

In an environment, say

```
\newenvironment{whatever}[3]{...}{...}
```

you instantiante it (if that's the word for it in LaTeX) by

```
\begin{whatever}{first}{second}{third}
   ...
\end{whatever}
```

But how do you define an environment such that you instantiate it by

```
\begin{whatever}[some_optional]{first}{second}{third}
   ...
\end{whatever}
```

I'm not talking about default values for the parameters `first`, `second` or `third`, but an entirely optional parameter, such as in

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    ...         ^--- THIS!
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{whatever}[4][??]
  {...}
  {...}

\begin{whatever}{one}{two}{three}

is #1= {??}
   #2= one
   #3= two
   #4= three

\begin{whatever}[zero]{one}{two}{three}

is #1= zero
   #2= one
   #3= two
   #4= three

\newenvironment{whatever}[4][foo]
  {...}
  {...}

\begin{whatever}{one}{two}{three}

is #1= foo % preset to foo, if missing
   #2= one
   #3= two
   #4= three

\begin{whatever}[bar]{one}{two}{three}

is #1= bar   % the optional argument 
   #2= one
   #3= two
   #4= three
```

Comment: I dont understand the 4th case \newenvironment{whatever}[4][foo]

Comment: [4][foo] defines 4 parameter in which the first one #1 is optional and replaced by `foo` if it is not set by the user otherwise with the user value

Comment: In the first example `is #1= {}` implies that an empty optional argument is replaced by an empty brace group when it actually really is empty. One would need to input `\begin{whatever}[{{}}]]{...}...` to actually get the empty brace group.

Answer (score 21):

The [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy user interface to specify optional arguments to environments (in various orders) including commands/macros. For this you define your environment using `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, while regular macros use `\NewDocumentCommand`. The former has the following syntax:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{<env>}{<arg spec>}{<beg env>}{<end env>}
```

`<env>`, `<beg env>` and `<end env>` act in the traditional way to define the environment `<env>` that executes code `<beg env>` when using `\begin{<env>}` (or `\<env>`) and executes `<end env>` when using `\end{<env>}` (or `\end<env>`). `<arg spec>` contains a sequence of argument specifications to the environment that can intermix optional and mandatory arguments as needed. In short, this is how they are specified (omitting some options; for more details, read the [`xparse` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf)):

- `m` - a *mandatory* argument (requires `{ }`)
- `o` - an *optional* argument (uses `[ ]`)
- `O{<default>}` - an *optional* argument similar to `o` but returns `<default>` if the argument is not given (uses `[ ]`)
- `d<token1><token2>` - an *optional* argument with special delimiters (uses `<token1> <token2>`)
- `D<token1><token2>{<default>}` - an *optional* argument similar to `d` but returns `<default>` if the argument is not given (uses `<token1> <token2>`)

Here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{whatever}{m o O{foobar} m}{}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{whomever}{O{yes} D(){no}}{}{}

% #1=foo; #2=\NoValue; #3=foobar; #4=bar
\begin{whatever}{foo}{bar} foo \end{whatever}

% #1=foo; #2=bar; #3=foobar; #4=bar
\begin{whatever}{foo}[bar]{bar} foo \end{whatever}

% #1=yes; #2=no
\begin{whomever} foo \end{whomever}

% #1=no; #2=yes
\begin{whomever}[no](yes) foo \end{whomever}

\end{document}
```

As is obvious, this interface extends the existing "single optional argument" specification to a much wider range.